# replace substrings from within Hebrew text

Tags: c#, performance, strings

I have a string of Hebrew text which also contains":", "-", & "|".
Attempting to replace "-", "|", and ":" with a space.
How can I do this efficiently?

```
string my_string = "עַל־פְּנֵי:על־פני|על־פני";
string[] replace_chars = new string[] {":","-","|"};
foreach (string char_change in replace_chars){
    if(char_change == ":" || char_change == "-" || char_change == "|"){
       my_string = my_string.Replace(char_change, " ");
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any alternative to have this done ?

Comment: You can look at this stackoverflow question https://stackoverflow.com/q/7265315.  Pretty much covers all the options. from regex to string split to linq

Comment: Your code does not follow the Microsoft guidelines: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/general-naming-conventions : "DO NOT use underscores, hyphens, or any other nonalphanumeric characters." Also, you use the word "char" when in reality it is a string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can always use `Replace` extension, it's fast, durable, and under your hands. So, your work would be something like :

```
const char space = '\u0020'; // for readability purpose.

var result = my_string.Replace(':', space).Replace('-', space).Replace('|', space);
```

or if you have larger strings or you think it would be executed repeatedly, you can always use `StringBuilder`.

```
const char space = '\u0020'; // for readability purpose.

var builder = new StringBuilder(my_string);

var result = builder
    .Replace(':', space)
    .Replace('-', space)
    .Replace('|', space)
    .ToString();
```